For use of the OpenAI API in Android Studio, does something need to be done with the Content Negotiation from Ktor?
I am trying to develop an app as well as learn Kotlin. I decided to create an app that allows a User to create a story using AI, based on prompts, a sort of Text RPG game. I finished the UI, so now I moved on to incorporating the OpenAI API into the app. I finished writing the Kotlin code for the API request:
fun makeAPIRequest(message: String) {
        // Launch a coroutine to handle the API request asynchronously
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Create a ChatCompletionRequest to send to OpenAI
            val chatRequest = ChatCompletionRequest(
                model = ModelId("gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"), // Use the correct model name
                messages = mutableListOf(
                    ChatMessage(
                        role = Role.User, // User sends the message
                        content = message  // The message entered by the user
                    )
                ),
                temperature = 0.7,
                maxTokens = 150
            )

            // Send the request to OpenAI API and get the response asynchronously
            val response = openAI.chatCompletion(chatRequest)

            // Process the response on the main thread
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val responseMessage = response.choices.first().message
                // Handle the response here, e.g., update UI or process data
                chatGPTResponse = responseMessage.toString()
            }
        }
    }

The reason I didn't make the function async is because I call it elsware in my MainActivity.kt
There are no syntax errors when the project is just sitting inside the IDE. However, when I try to launch the app, it crashes instantly and gives me this output in Logcat:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/ktor/client/plugins/contentnegotiation/ContentNegotiation;

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~PDlu8hz4gyE6dIA4WjsxSA==/com.example.worldcrafter-jSXV8Rrpgh6Ga_DxfOZ7qg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~PDlu8hz4gyE6dIA4WjsxSA==/com.example.worldcrafter-jSXV8Rrpgh6Ga_DxfOZ7qg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~PDlu8hz4gyE6dIA4WjsxSA==/com.example.worldcrafter-jSXV8Rrpgh6Ga_DxfOZ7qg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

The reason I point out that second and longer replica of the first error is because before the app even starts, there is 2 warnings that It cannot access that exact file path
com.example.worldcrafter             W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~PDlu8hz4gyE6dIA4WjsxSA==/com.example.worldcrafter-jSXV8Rrpgh6Ga_DxfOZ7qg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-12-12 11:50:03.402 20454-20454 ziparchive
com.example.worldcrafter             W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~PDlu8hz4gyE6dIA4WjsxSA==/com.example.worldcrafter-jSXV8Rrpgh6Ga_DxfOZ7qg==/base.dm': No such file or directory

Here are my implementations:
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.recyclerview)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
    implementation("com.aallam.openai:openai-client:3.8.2")
    implementation(platform(libs.ktor.bom))
    //not using the toml file because i hate it with a burning passion
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:3.0.2")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:3.0.2")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:3.0.2")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:3.0.2")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:3.0.2")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:3.0.2")
}

And here is my MainActivity.kt, which I have slimmed down to only the relevant functions and variables, as it also handles UI switches.
package com.example.worldcrafter

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.aallam.openai.api.chat.*
import com.aallam.openai.api.model.ModelId
import com.aallam.openai.api.core.Role
import com.aallam.openai.api.http.Timeout
import com.aallam.openai.client.OpenAI
import com.aallam.openai.client.OpenAIConfig
import com.example.worldcrafter.ui.adapters.ChatAdapter
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import kotlinx.coroutines.DelicateCoroutinesApi
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds

import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

// App startup
class MainActivity() : ComponentActivity() {

    val openAI = OpenAI(OpenAIConfig(BuildConfig.OPENAI_API_KEY, timeout = Timeout(socket = 60.seconds)))

    var chatGPTResponse: String = ""

    // on creation of app
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Initialize the buttons in the Chat layout
    private fun initChatButtons() {
        // Setup navigation buttons
        setupButton(R.id.btSavedChats2) { switchLayout(LayoutType.SAVED_CHATS) }
        setupButton(R.id.btSettings2) { switchLayout(LayoutType.SETTINGS) }

        // Initialize mutable list to store messages
        val messages = mutableListOf<String>()

        // Set up RecyclerView and Adapter
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        val chatAdapter = ChatAdapter(messages) // Use ChatAdapter directly
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = chatAdapter

        // Reference to TextInputEditText
        val inputEditText = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.textInputEditText)

        // Set an action listener to detect "Enter" key
        inputEditText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || (event != null && event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                val message = inputEditText.text.toString().trim()

                if (message.isNotEmpty()) {
                    // Use addMessage() instead of direct list manipulation
                    chatAdapter.addMessage(message)

                    // Scroll to the latest message
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1)

                    //chatgpt message here
                    makeAPIRequest(message)

                    // Add the response to the list
                    chatAdapter.addMessage(chatGPTResponse)

                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1)

                    // Clear the input field
                    inputEditText.text?.clear()

                    // Hide the keyboard after the message is added
                    hideKeyboard()

                    return@setOnEditorActionListener true
                }
            }
            false
        }
    }

    //chatgpt stuff
    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun makeAPIRequest(message: String) {
        // Launch a coroutine to handle the API request asynchronously
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Create a ChatCompletionRequest to send to OpenAI
            val chatRequest = ChatCompletionRequest(
                model = ModelId("gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"), // Use the correct model name
                messages = mutableListOf(
                    ChatMessage(
                        role = Role.User, // User sends the message
                        content = message  // The message entered by the user
                    )
                ),
                temperature = 0.7,
                maxTokens = 150
            )

            // Send the request to OpenAI API and get the response asynchronously
            val response = openAI.chatCompletion(chatRequest)

            // Process the response on the main thread
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val responseMessage = response.choices.first().message
                // Handle the response here, e.g., update UI or process data
                chatGPTResponse = responseMessage.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}


I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, using different versions of both Content Negotiation, Kotlin, and the entirety of Ktor. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

have you checked BuildConfig.OPENAI_API_KEY. Make sure the API_KEY is properly defined in build.gradle or your project configuration.
Or ensure all resources and files required for the app are properly included in the project.

Thank you for the suggestion, I will try that

This is what is in my build.gradle file.
android {
//shortened to fit
buildConfigField(
"String",
"OPENAI_API_KEY",
""${project.findProperty("OPENAI_API_KEY")}""
)
}
do you see anything wrong? the key is declared in gradle.properties, and I have been pulling it off BuildConfig in my MainActivity without any errors

At configuration buildConfigField( "String", "OPENAI_API_KEY", ""${project.findProperty("OPENAI_API_KEY")}"" ), please replace ${project.findProperty("OPENAI_API_KEY")} to your api key.
PS. I have just run this app successfully.

thank you for the attempt, but I still crash. I don't believe the issue is in buildConfig, because even if I create the openAi object by directly passing the API key as a parameter, I still get the same error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/ktor/client/plugins/contentnegotiation/ContentNegotiation;
I also get these warnings above the error:

2024-12-15 20:00:41.487 22537-22537 ziparchive Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.worldcrafter/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dm': No such file or directory
2024-12-15 20:00:41.488 22537-22537 ziparchive              com.example.worldcrafter             W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~slGbyjJRuE0bMtknzaC9ng==/com.example.worldcrafter-snoLaXbVhIVRxQXsAED6XA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-12-15 20:00:41.488 22537-22537 ziparchive Unable to open '/data/app/~~slGbyjJRuE0bMtknzaC9ng==/com.example.worldcrafter-snoLaXbVhIVRxQXsAED6XA==/base.dm': No such file or directory

Found the solution!!! All I had to do was check what version of Ktor is compatible with allam-openai. Turns out, it was 2.3.2 instead of 3.0.2 which I was using.
It was all 1 ChatGPT search away :sobbing:
ChatGPT output
